# What is the best practice for an application that provides an embeddable widget?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

So take intercom, drift or any 3rd party interactive widget.

The end result being a snippet of code, that then builds an iframe? and controls sizing while allowing for cross origin requests. Is this really the best way to do this when offering an embeddable widget from SiteA.com to SiteB.com ?

It's my understanding that if I wanted to offer an embedded widget, I would create javascript snippet that added an iframe to the host's webpage, that iframe then displays the component. Only caveats I see is sizing of a responsive widget would also have to be in the snippet.

Curious if this is the **standard** way to do this, or if there is something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is one way to do it,

however, if you really don't need/want iframe you can also provide a javascript package.
you can host this package on your end, or provide it via public CDN